# Where can I put ACTION_UP in my code so it works?

Tags: java, android, touch

I have code for a circle to appear `onTouchListener` and follow a finger around the screen. Now I'm working on getting it to disappear when the finger is taken off the screen. I'm pretty sure `ACTION_UP:` is what I need. I just don't know how to implement it.

This is the code I want to go inside the `ACTION_UP`

```
   paint.setARGB(1, r, g, b);
```

And here is the relavant code so far:

```
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    paint.setARGB(255, r, g, b);

    //drawing the circle
    canvas.drawCircle(x,y,radius,paint);

}

public boolean onTouch(View view,MotionEvent event)
{
    x=(int)event.getX()-(radius/2);      //logic to plot the circle in exact touch place
    y=(int)event.getY()-(radius/2);
      //System.out.println("X,Y:"+"x"+","+y);      
    randColor();  //color of circle
    invalidate();    
    return true;
        //where I think I need to put ACTION_UP...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like that:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Your code...
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I literally just got it working like this, except I returned true. Thanks for the answer :